# Timeout error when writing large amounts of data to big query

Tags: sql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am getting the following error when trying to write large amounts of data to big query using

```
client.insert_rows_json()

google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

method. I have tried modifying the timeout parameter in the following way:

```
client.insert_rows_json(*args, timeout=1000000)
```

but I still get the same timeout error where the deadline is still at 600.0s.

Is there someway to establish the client with:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_json)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id)
```

and specify how long before timeout should occur?

Comment: What environment are you running this in?

Could you split the rows into smaller batches and make multiple smaller insert_rows_json calls instead of single larger one?

Comment: @Luka I ended up doing this and it works fine and honestly it seems to run much faster doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Load the service account credentials
service_account_json = 'path/to/service_account.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_json)

# Create the client with the desired timeout value
client = bigquery.Client(
    credentials=credentials,
    project=credentials.project_id,
    default_query_job_config=bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
        timeout=1800,  # Set the timeout to 1800 seconds (30 minutes)
    ),
)
```

Comment: This produces the following error:   AttributeError: Property timeout is unknown for <class 'google.cloud.bigquery.job.query.QueryJobConfig'>.